# Is there a way to prevent screen readers from reading table info?

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm working on a web page for a project and currently we are using a table to control the layout of content.When a screen reader (I'm testing with NVDA) focuses on the first item in the table, it speaks "Table with 7 rows and 3 columns" and then reads the item.

```
<table role="presentation">
    <tr>
        <td tabindex="0" class="bold">Item</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to prevent the screen reader from speaking the table information? I've tried setting the role to presentation and it still speaks it. I know using tables as a means of designing layout is bad practice, but this is for a prototype.

Thanks

Comment: "but this is for a prototype" this sounds awfully like those people who say something like "it's just temporary". Just fix your html.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using tables for layout, just make sure they're responsive so that if the text size is increased (wcag 1.4.4), it'll reflow properly and not truncate text.  Having tabindex is fine too.  And you are correctly using role=presentation.  No screen reader should tell you it's a table if that role is specified.  If it does, then the reader has a bug.  From the limited info you have posted, you are doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Providing a URL would allow us to test it to hear what you hear. Telling us what version of NVDA you are using would help. Knowing the browser you are using is also hugely important as they expose different things through their accessibility APIs. So please provide the following:

1. URL for testing,
2. The version of NVDA you are using,
3. The web browser you are using with NVDA.

As for compatibility expectations, there is a handy chart tracking issues (last updated in October 2016):

- [Layout table with role presentation: Screen reader compatibility](http://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/tables/table-role-presentation-layout-table/)

Per that site it should perform well for these combinations:

> Good: NVDA with IE Stable - OK from NVDA 2014.1 to NVDA 2016.2
>
> Good: NVDA with FF Stable - OK from NVDA 2014.1 to NVDA 2016.2

Also, I see `tabindex` on the cell. A screen reader user does not need it to get to the content. When you remove it, does NVDA behave?

Two overall recommendations:

1. Do not use tables for layout, even for prototyping;
2. Remove the `tabindex` from everything unless you are also adding all the necessary roles and keyboard interaction to truly make it an interactive control.

Comment: I'm unable to provide a URL because it's on the internal company network only. I'm using NVDA 2016.3 and IE 11

Comment: Can you make a CodePen / JSBin demo with your code? Did you try removing `tabindex`?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/yefapavuqi/edit?html
I tried removing tabindex, but I need it because otherwise, the user cannot tab to the item in the cell. The linked web page works perfectly fine in chrome, but not IE. Could this issue be just a quirk of IE?

Comment: I am confused why you think the user needs to tab to the item in the cell. Screen reader users typically do not tab around a page to get content. See my point #2 above since you are making it a de facto interactive control. Regardless, I tested in NVDA 2016.3 in IE11, Firefox and Chrome. Does not announce as a table. I suggest you look at your NVDA settings ("Include layout tables", perhaps?).

Comment: Changing the "Include layout tables" option does not change the behavior. That's good to know. I can try removing it, but the next item in the table is a button and the same behavior occurs with the button. I was just using a label as a simple example. I'm thinking at this point, I should just look into rewriting everything to not use a table for the layout. I was just hoping to not need to. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah, you may very well be stuck. I cannot reproduce it using your examples with a similar (but maybe not the same) configuration. You can [file an issue with NVDA](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues) if you feel it is a bug.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways I know of:

This will make it invisible to nvda:

```
aria-hidden = true
```

This makes the element not focusable:

```
Tab-Index="-1"
```

Comment: `>role="presentation" will behave or will be equivalent to aria-hidden=true.`  Sorry, that is not true.  `role="presentation"` will remove the semantics of the element but the text is still there and available to a screen reader.  `aria-hidden` hides the element completely from a screen reader.  regarding `tabindex`, there is no dash in the attribute name.